# SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters

Tags: javascript, function

I was trying to implement recaptcha on my website, so I created a callback function using javascript which should be executed when a user submits a successful captcha response:

```
<script>
   function onSubmit = function(token) {
      document.getElementById("form-signin").submit();
   }
</script>
```

But always got this error `SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters` when using Firefox.

When using Google Chrome, I got this error instead: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Both browsers indicate that the error is located at `function onSubmit = function(token) {`, but I don't know why this happened.

Can anyone be so kind as to tell me what is wrong?

Comment: you should try var onSubmit =

Comment: How I got this error: I didn't get enough sleep and for some reason I though I can use dashes (mathematical operators for subtraction) in function names. For anyone wondering and stumbling upon the same error, you can't (obviously; it's subtraction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic ways to declare a named function:

```
function onSubmit(token){
    document.getElementById("form-signin").submit();
}
```

Or:

```
var onSubmit = function(token){
    document.getElementById("form-signin").submit();
};
```

In your case, just go with the first.

Comment: @DavidThomas I know. The point is that the second way can be confusing to beginners, because it blurs the lines between functions and variables. They can be treated the same, which is useful for HOF, closures, etc. But the first is easier to understand when you're starting javascript, IMHO.

Comment: in my case, `jQuery.my_function = function(){ ... };` was only possible and the `;` was missing. the `function jQuery.my_function(){ ... }` definitely doesn't work.

Comment: @Meloman Yes, that's a good point. When you have an existing object (like `jQuery` in your case), you cannot declare a new function on it using the first syntax. The [first version](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-function-definitions) only accepts a Javascript [identifier](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-BindingIdentifier), not a full object path.

Answer (score 2):

`function some_identifier` can start either a function declaration or a function expression. Either way, the next characters must be `(` then any argument definitions, then `)`.

If you want to assign the result of evaluating a function expression to a variable, as you are trying to do here, then you must declare the variable *in the normal way* (i.e. with the `var` keyword, unless you have declared it already, or are not using strict mode and want to create a global).

So either:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
  document.getElementById("form-signin").submit();
}
```

or

```
var onSubmit = function(token) {
  document.getElementById("form-signin").submit();
}
```